# How to choose a christmas tree proper for my pets?

Tags: cats, dogs, fish, rabbits, toys

When it comes to buy a christmas tree, what precautions can I take, to choose one, my pets have an advantage from?

I have in mind to use it as a toy/entertainment for my pet **after it was used in my room as decoration**.

Answer (score 3):

Answer for **rabbits**:

First of all, you need to choose a tree, that was not or minimal treated with fertilizers and insectizides. Both would stay in the wood and needles for a long time and are not healthy for rabbits. I.e. you can look for events of lokal forest associations. They regularly cut trees from spaces like under hifg voltage lines and you can buy them, or even go with a staffmember and choose and cut your own.

The second point is the kind of christmas tree. Some sorts are poisonous for rabbits. In general this ones at home in northern europe are mostly not toxic to them, i.e. fir (family of latin "Abies") or spruce (latin "Picea").

Next you also should not use any additive in the water, which would harm your rabbits and also no syntetic snow or similar, which is not removable from the needles anymore.

The last point is, that you need to remove all pieces of decoration careful from the whole tree before you give it to your rabbits.

Mine enjoy to eat the young branches and needles. I used to make small tent-like hutches out of the branches, so they can hide inside but have full vision of their surrounding.

**Fun fact**: rabbits have fur inside their mouth. Left and right inside the cheeks they have it, so they get not hurt by eating needles and small thorns.